# how to resolve this cycle in dependencies swift

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, promisekit

Does anyone know how I could resolve this cycle in dependencies? I've been stuck on this problem for 3 days. I tried build cleans, clearing derived data, rebuilding pods, even doing git reverts are not helping. [image: Error]

```
error: Cycle in dependencies between targets 'Pods-Trust' and 'PromiseKit'; 
building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle path: Pods-Trust → PromiseKit → Pods-Trust
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Pods-Trust' has target dependency on Target 'PromiseKit'
→ Target 'PromiseKit' has link command with output '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Payd-ampguiegvrhgtrfmpddfkkwgmpnf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/PromiseKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PromiseKit'
○ Target 'PromiseKit' has a command with output '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Payd-ampguiegvrhgtrfmpddfkkwgmpnf/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/PromiseKit/PromiseKit.framework/PromiseKit'
```

Answer (score 1):

Had similar thing few times - try to delete derived data + clean project + `pod install` ... at least it worked for me